# Is it ok to have multiple UIViewControllers in a UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

(my first question here ;)

I am trying to implement the functionality that you can see in mail: where there is a up en down button to load previous or next mail.

In my case I have a UITableView with around 100 entries and if you select a row, a huge empty UIScrollView is loaded. And shown at the right offset where a DetailView is loaded. In this huge scrollview (with paging enabled) each page is the size of the screen.
The DetailView contains a UIScrollview in which the content (text) and some buttons to do stuff (mail, open link in safari etc) are displayed.

I use a (DetailView *)dequeueRecycledPage method that uses an NSSet so there are max 3 UIViewControllers alive. (current, previous, next). For fast response.

The buttons in the navbar will tell the huge scrollview to "scrollRectToVisible:animated:YES" so the user sees the new view slide in.

Right now my DetailView is subclassed from UIView, and it works. But I don't want a lot of delegation for the button actions in this DetailView. I'd rather have the DetailView handle them.
So I would like to subclass my DetailView from UIViewController. 
But then we have the huge empty scrollview with 3 UIViewControllers (only 1 displayed at a time). But maybe that Apple is not keen on this, or maybe I run into trouble somehow.

So my question comes down to this:

- Can a UIScrollView contain more than one UIViewControllers (only 1 displayed at a time)
  Or is this "not done" or simply wrong?

thanks in advance for your help,
G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is theoretically possible for one UIScrollView to contains the UIViews of 3 different UIViewControllers, it is not necessarily the best practice for what you are trying to accomplish.

Typically, a better design would be to have your UIScrollView belong to a UIViewController and then you can add whatever UIViews (or subclasses there of) to your UIScrollView. Instead of creating 3 different UIViewControllers and adding their views to your UIScrollView, you could simply create 3 different UIViews and add those views to your UIScrollView.

Comment: hey, thanks. I guess this is the way to go. I should stick to the MVC paradigm.

Comment: I know I'm late to the party here but doesn't this break the whole idea of having a UIViewController with a "single job"? I was about to ask a similar question. Each of the views in my paging scroll view is complex with a UITableView and each has their own server requests etc... Putting this all in to one UIViewController seems like the wrong way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can have two (thus multiple) views within one scroll view, the company I work for has done it a couple of times.

I'm not sure what the exact code is, but you'll probably want something like:

```
myScrollView.addSubView(viewName).
```

To hide the view, do this:

```
if (logicToHideViewIsTrue) {
    [viewName setHidden:YES];
 }
```

More information can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/CreatingBasicScrollViews/CreatingBasicScrollViews.html)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a UIViewController encompasses an entire screen and only one should be visible at a time.  The way to implement the Mail app view involves a UINavigationController, a UIViewController and a UIScrollView.

The UIViewController should add the Up/Down buttons to the navigation toolbar.

The UIViewController has a view that should be a UIScrollView.  When an Up/Down button is press, the UIViewController should receive this message and then tell the UIScrollView to change it's view to the new content.